# Is preschool closure (due to the pandemic) a qualifying event for Dependent Care FSA?

Tags: united-states, fsa, covid-19, child-care

I'm trying to figure out of closure of my daughter's preschool meets the qualifying event criteria so that I can reduce my dependent care FSA contributions. I've read a few places online that change of cost of care meets the criteria but I cannot find anything about that on the IRS website.

Can anyone provide a link to something authoritative? I'd like to include that in my email to the HR department at my employer with the request to reduce the contributions.

Comment: Did you or your spouse change employment status (furloughed, laid off?) or are otherwise now home with the child? Also, your best bet would be to check the website of the plan administrator. I looked at 2, and both say change in cost or care coverage is a QLE.

Comment: No employment change, but we can't send her to school so we're just throwing money away with that deduction.

Comment: I totally understand. Like I said, check with the administrator of your FSA plan, but both fsafeds dot com and wageworks dot come say that the IRS defines a QLE and include change in daycae provider cost or coverage as a QLE.

Comment: I don't have a link to an authoritative source, but I can confirm that I was able to stop contributions to my dependent care FSA based on daycare being closed, and I will be able to start contributions again when daycare reopens. As far as I understand, this was existing policy and not something specially implemented for the pandemic.

Comment: Do you expect the preschool to stay closed for the remainder of the year?